# Exchange 2010 mailbox appearing twice through automapping

Tags: exchange-2010

We have an issue that has recently appeared where a mailbox is being mapped twice.

First - We give a user full mailbox access to a shared drive, lets call it Shared(email: Shared@domain.com).

It's then automapped as Shared and appears in their list. This is how it's always behaved (since automapping first appeared.)

They also need to send from the Shared account so we have to add the account in as a separate email account so that the sent items go into the correct Sent items (the shared one).

Now this is where things are suddenly behaving differently. Adding the mail account for shared means it is being mapped a second time to the folder/mailbox list in outlook (2016 if it matters).

Once as Shared and once as shared@domain.com
Both accounts seem to match and have the same mail inside, messages in the outbox appear in both.

Any idea what's suddenly causing this? And what's the best way to fix it?

Only exchange changes we have made recently is changing our certificates to match our new company name and updating them throughout outlook. I don't know if they are related, just giving all the information for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the above comment, it seemed to be treating them as 2 separate accounts. Editing the shared user account security permissions and giving the user 'send as' access to the account seems to have fixed it, only 1 mailbox shows now and items sent from the shared account leave the outbox and go correctly into the right sent items.

I can't explain why this fixes it, but it has. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the shared mailbox as an additional ACCOUNT, or additional MAILBOX? They are two different methods. If you add it as an additional account, then it shouldn't map automatically.

Comment: account, we don't use additional mailboxes. To go into the right Sent Items we need to add it as an additional account.

Comment: It suggests to me that Outlook is not recognising that the account you have added and the account being added via Auto Mapping are the same. I have been using the additional account method since the release of Outlook 2010. The only time you see duplication is immediately after making the change. When you restart Outlook it should go away as Outlook recognises it. Something with that account would be my guess.

Comment: Yes, that IS usual behaviour, unfortunately restarting outlook this time does not make it go away. They are treated as different accounts, I think it must be some kind of permission issue, as it's causing emails to get stuck in the outbox if I use the default From entry for shared@domain.com. If I select 'other' in the from box and type the address manually it then sends from the other of the 2 mailboxes, which I think of as the "send as" mailbox because it will send then, but goes into the users sent items, not the shared one. I think I have this licked now, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to do, but perhaps a different approach will give you the wanted result.

First, setup the shared mailbox (Shared@domain.com).

Then in EMC add the users who should have access to the mailbox by granting them full access.

After that you are right they will see the mailbox in their Outlook profile but they will not be able to send mail from the shared mailbox yet. There are a few more things you need to do.

If you manually add the mailbox to the profile as you are doing then yes you will end up with two of that mailbox in each Outlook profile. Yes, this will let you send from that mailbox but there is another way to do that without causing the duplication.

To allow the users to send mail from the shared mailbox you need to grant them Send As permissions. You can do this in EMC or in Exchange PowerShell.

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Shared@domain.com" -User UserToBeGrantedPermission -AccessRights SendAs -InheritanceType All
```

You might wonder why you need to explicity give a user SendAs rights when you already gave them FullAccess. It is a fair question and the answer is that FullAccess does not include permission to send email from the mailbox to which the user was granted FullAccess rights.

> Full Access   The delegate can open the mailbox and do anything except send messages.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919240(v=exchg.160).aspx

If you grant a user FullAccess and SendAs for the shared mailbox you should not need to manaully add the mailbox to that Outlook profile and email sent from the shared mailbox should go to the correct Sent Items folder.

It is also worth mentioning for the user to be able to send email from this shared mailbox after you give their user the correct permissions their Outlook profile needs to get the updated Offline Address Book from Exchange. Until it gets the updated Offline Address Book from Exchange, they will get an error any time they try to send an email from the shared mailbox. You can resolve that by closing Outlook, closing Skype for Business, opening %userprofile%\appdata\local\microsoft\outlook\offline address book, deleting the contents, then opening Outlook. You can also solve the error by disabling cached exchange mode for the Outlook profile. A third option is to force an update of the Offline Address Book from EMC.

Comment: So you're saying that giving Send As permission will put the sent items in the right folder negating the need to add it in as an account? I'm certainly willing to give it a shot. Will let you know my results.

Comment: This method solves several problems, usually it includes what Sent Items folder to which sent emails are directed. If this does not fix that specific error there is a registry change you can make that should fix it.

Comment: OK, I've tested it. The emails send because they have permission, but they do not go into the correct Sent Items folder. Yes there is a registry entry I can use to redirect it but that's not feasible to roll out. Adding it as an account has always worked without automapping it before now and redirected the mail properly, I'd rather just understand/fix why it's suddenly started adding it twice when it's not done that before if possible.

Comment: The registry method is the old way of dealing with this issue. The add account is the new preferred method. 
Granting Send As does NOTHING to change the behaviour of the Sent Items folder. It is just a permission change which you should have already have set when using the add additional account method.

Comment: You can easily roll out the registry tweak using group policy.

Comment: @Sembee the registry method may be the "old" way of dealing with this issue by what you proposed is what the OP is doing and what is causing the problem. My solution is tested and works.